# Calling controller methods from view with jquery asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have two methods in a controller: `Page` and `Load`. `Page` returns `view` but `Load` returns `JsonResult`. I also have a view with `jquery-functions` where I call my methods.

They execute in order but I want to call them asynchronously. How do I do that?

```
function **LoadPage**(page, isnext) {
    $(':focus').blur();
    $('#loadingBlockElement').show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("page", new { formId = Model.Params.FormId, userId = Model.Params.UserId, baseVersion = Model.Params.BaseVersion, stateName = Model.Params.StateName, stateVersion = Model.Params.StateVersion, stateFormId = Model.Params.StateFormId, baseFormId = Model.Params.BaseFormId }))'+'&page='+page+'&isnext='+isnext,         

        success: function (result) {     
            $('body').find('.ui-dialog').find('div').remove();        
            $('body').find('.ui-dialog').remove();      
            WE = null;
            $('#main').html(result);
            $('form').hide();
        }
    });
}

function **Load**() {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("load")"+'?userId=@Model.Params.UserId'+'&formId=@Model.Params.FormId'+'&baseVersion=@Model.Params.BaseVersion'+'&stateFormId=@Model.Params.StateFormId'+'&baseFormId=@Model.Params.BaseFormId'+'&stateName=@Model.Params.StateName'+'&stateVersion=@Model.Params.StateVersion'+'&page='+$('form:first').attr('ID'),
        success: function (result) {..bla-bla-bla
```

**Controller**:

**Load:**

```
public JsonResult Load(int formId, int baseVersion, string stateName, int stateVersion, string page, string userId, int stateFormId, int baseFormId)
{
     ...
}
```

**Page:**

```
public ActionResult Page(int formId, int baseVersion, string stateName, int stateVersion, string page, string userId, bool? isNext, int stateFormId, int baseFormId)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, this is what you need http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: I need to call my methods async. They should executing in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ajax` property to **true** on both of the `$.ajax` calls [as the documentation shows](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), then call each function subsequently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadPage(page);
    Load();
});

function LoadPage(page) {
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       async: true, // this is what you're missing
       url: "yoururl",
       success: function (result) {
           // handle success
       }
   });
}

function Load() {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true, // this is what you're missing
        url: "yoururl",
        success: function (result) {
            // handle success
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So, I don't need to use any attributes for async operations in my controller?

Comment: @NickitaFabregas no, controller action is a server side function whether you call it asynchronously or not. The only thing you need to concern yourself with is the client - in this case your jQuery ajax call.